# OrderBy custom attribute

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've created a custom attribute for a model, and would like to orderBy that that attribute (sortBy is not the solution), after ordering it by that attribute I need to paginate it which is also happening in the query.

This is my current code:

```
$result = TheEpisode::where('seriesID', $id)->paginate(12);
```

Before I paginate, I need to orderBy custom attribute - `largestNumber` ?

Is this possible?

Comment: How you are getting `largestNumber`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**By Laravel.com**:  The orderBy method allows you to sort the result of the query by a given column. The first argument to the orderBy method should be the column you wish to sort by, while the second argument controls the direction of the sort and may be either asc or desc:

Try this

```
$result = TheEpisode::where('seriesID', $id)
            ->orderBy('name', 'desc')
            ->paginate(12);
```

References: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

Comment: I need to order custom attribute.

Comment: what is your custom attribute? please explain :) you can set any `fieldname` instead of `'name'`

Comment: custom attribute is the one set inside model: getHighestEpisodeAttribute

Comment: Please post details about model, controller and database design.